# Titanium Appcelerator get number of satellites

Tags: geolocation, gps, location, titanium, appcelerator

Is it possible to get information on number of gps satellites connected through Titanium Appcelerator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such method in titanium but if you have this method in native(Dont know exactly myself).You could always build a module and integrate in your app.here is method of building modules

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Android_Module_Development_Guide

https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/iOS+Module+Development+Guide

Thanks